# How to get the out of the box slideshow to display on a page other than /node? - Corporate Clean/Omega theme

Tags: theming

I am using a domain access module and currently running two domains. Out of the box, my default domain was displaying a slideshow on the homepage. Using these [instructions](http://wiki.morethanthemes.com/index.php?title=Corporate_Clean%3aDemonstration_Content_for_Drupal_7.x#Slideshow) I created a new front page -

However, now the slideshow isn't displaying. How do I get it back up?

By the way, the reason I went ahead with the front page setup as per the instructions was to avoid the "No front page content has been created yet." message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was displaying the slideshow correctly out of the box (i.e. without any modifications made), then you should be able set the default front page back to its original state (empty... i.e. delete whatever's currently in the box), then add a file in the theme directory called `page--front.tpl.php`. Inside that file, copy/paste the original code found inside the file `page.tpl.php`.

Assuming you're using the Corporate Clean theme, scroll down your new `page--front.tpl.php` file about 220 lines and change this line:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

... so that it's commented out:

```
<?php // print render($page['content']); ?>
```

... Or, if all you want to do is simply remove the *No front page content has been created yet* message, you can hide the default message and then print the rest of the content like normal (i.e. instead of changing the line, just add another one right above it):

```
<?php hide($page['content']['system_main']['default_message']); ?>
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Or, you could just delete that line but I assume you'll eventually want some content there (in which case you can go back and undo the commenting out).

After you've completed all the changes, saved all the files, etc, go to `admin/config/development/performance` and clear all the caches -- the new front page should now appear with the slideshow and without any "No front page content has been created yet" content.

Hope that helps...

:)

Comment: Thanks @jerdiggity
Doing this did remove the "No front page content has been created yet." text, but it also removed all the content including the block I had in the content area, which is not what I want.

Comment: Gotcha. See latest revision.